# Is there a difference between brown and white champignons?

Tags: mushrooms

My supermarket sells two varieties of champignons: Brown and white, with the brown ones being slightly more expensive.

Is there any notable difference between brown and white champignons in how they taste or the way you prepare or store them? Or is it rather like with brown and white chicken eggs where the differences are literally superficial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this site: [What’s the difference between cremini and white mushrooms?](https://www.therecord.com/living-story/7201972-what-s-the-difference-between-cremini-and-white-mushrooms-/)

Brown(Baby Bella or Cremini) mushrooms have earthier flavor than the whites, you could use them based on your dishes' style or presentation.

And the storing should be the same. Put them in some brown bag with normal temperature and do not freeze them. Slightly wipe the dust or dirt just before cooking, no need to wash by water.

Comment: EG brown ones are more expensive because they are older versions of the same mushroom. Requiring a longer growing time = more expensive to cultivate.

Comment: Steve: they're not older, they're just a different coloration (and flavor) of the same species.  Portabellos are older, those are the full-size, mature versions of the same mushroom.  The brown ones are sometimes more expensive (but not always) because "cremini" sounds more gourmet than "button mushroom".